# Why does my android app crashes when I implement android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Long story short, I develop a simple android java app to which I wish to implement some ads using the adsense service. The app itself works and does its purpose, but once I add the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0' in the gradle mobile module, the app crashes.

I also tried to complete all the possible necessary steps, including the android name & value metadata part in the Android manifest, and also set up the ads with libraries and the function of MobileAds.initialize() in the Main Activity.

I followed the steps in here:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

but as i tried to isolate the problem, I saw that by only including the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0' in the gradle mobile script (together with the google() spec in the repository) the app crashes from the start. It doesn't even enter.

What can I do? Why does this happen? I'll be glad if I receive some help.

Comment: *"What can I do?"*  Start by looking for error messages and stacktraces in logcat.

Comment: Do you receive any error messages when crashing?

Comment: No error messages that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you've linked to includes this section: [Update your AndroidManifest.xml](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=import_the_mobile_ads_sdk#update_your_androidmanifestxml)

> **Important:** This step is required as of Google Mobile Ads SDK version 17.0.0. Failure to add this `<meta-data>` tag results in a crash with the message: **The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly.**

You've said that all you've done is add the dependency to your `build.gradle` file, so you've probably not done this step and that's your issue. You will need to [find your App ID](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6232340) and add it to `AndroidManifest.xml`, as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I already did that as well.

Comment: I upvoted yesterday because this worked for me **with a real app id**. I found today when trying to use the "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy" dummy number, that it insta-crashes with no output the same way it does when the metadata is not present. So I guess the documentation is lying when it says you can use the dummy app id in test application?

Comment: Update: Oh, I see now. The docs weren't saying that "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy" is a usable dummy number for test. There was a nearby comment saying that **"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"** is actually the usable one for testing. That works for me again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta data tag in menifest like the given example code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.WatchAndEarn"
    tools:targetApi="31"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3304471310252738~5701061203"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And in MainActivity use initialization like the example given below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
}
```